# Azure Notification Hub cannot send push notification to specific Tag

Tags: azure, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have registered devices in Azure Notification Hub (via cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps). It creates two entries: "**native**" with "**installationid**" tag and "**Template**" with all specified tags.

[image]

If I send message with "**installationid**" tag, it works fine:

[image]

But if i try to use any other tag, it couldn't find entry:

[image]
and tells "*Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets*".

I can find entries wihout any problem using VS diagnose tool "Filter by single tag" (first screenshot), but tags "invisible" during send for some reason.

It started to happen recently.

Any help or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should submit a support ticket in Azure portal for this. Without looking at particular hub and logs it's hard to tell why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may concern:
problem was with expired APNS certificate threw exception and blocked FCM part.

NB: neither Visual Studio test send, nor Service Bus Explorer can work with tags and templates, that poured much more confusion as broadcast worked fine.
Writing your own test tool helped solve this riddle.

Microsoft Tech Support gave rare, vague and obscure "Dark Souls"-like hints, that become clear only after you solve it.

Hope it will save time for someone.